# "Name or service not knownname" using SSH from script

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

Cannot connect to host by SSH.

I am using following shell script to use `ssh`.

```
host_list="c15-0330-14.ad.mtu.edu"
ssh "$host_list"
```

But It always says `: Name or service not knownname c15-0330-14.ad.mtu.edu`.

I tried `ssh c15-0330-14.ad.mtu.edu`. It works.
Also, If I have several hosts, how can I invoke them one by one?

Comment: As per my [try](http://prntscr.com/6x3vlc) it is working well enough. I don't understand why yours is not.

Comment: Works fine for me too. Voting to close.

Comment: Your script has DOS line endings, and needs to be converted to Unix line endings with something like `dos2unix`. The carriage return from the DOS line ending is part of `host_list`, which causes the error. Notice the odd error message, where `: Name or service not known` is overwriting the beginning of the error message.

Comment: @chepner. I edit the shell script under windows system. And Run it under linux system. Does this really matter?

Comment: @chepner You are right. I create the shell script under the linux. And it works now. I always use windows system to do my work and run program in linux. How can I create a "good" shell script for linux under the windows?

Comment: Yes, very much. `bash` assumes the script uses Unix line endings.

Comment: @chepner. Actually, I use `./test.sh` to run program which is created under the windows. And it works but the case in this post.

Comment: The version of `bash` on Windows presumably understands DOS line endings; the version compiled for Unix systems does not.

Comment: @AlexBrown, [`dos2unix`](http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/) is a tool designed specifically for the conversion you're looking for. It is likely available in the package manager you're using on your unix or linux system. Alternately, you can achieve the same thing using other tools; `tr -d "\r"` will remove all carriage returns regardless of their position in the line, and you can achieve similar or improved results using awk, sed, perl, etc.

Comment: Search for `[bash] is:answer dos2unix` on Stack Exchange to find *many* answers discussing the same problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error message *should* be

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname c15-0330-14.ad.mtu.edu: Name or service not known
```

except the DOS line endings in your script cause an extra carriage return to be stored at the end of the value of `host_list`. This carriage return, when printed as part of the error message, causes the cursor to return to the beginning of the line, resulting in the error message you actually see. Notice how the two halves line up (the carriage return immediately precedes the colon):

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname c15-0330-14.ad.mtu.edu
: Name or service not known
```

results in your error of

```
: Name or service not knownname c15-0330-14.ad.mtu.edu
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what should I do? Do you mean I only can edit file in linux? Actually I do not totally understand your answer. :)

Comment: Simply put, the value of `host_list` is not `c15-0330-14.ad.mtu.edu`, but `c15-0330-14.ad.mtu.edu\r`. The extra carriage return comes from the fact that you save the file in Windows, which uses `\r\n` to terminate lines, while the Linux `bash` expects lines to be terminated by only `\n`, so the `\r` is considered part of the line, rather than part of the line ending. You need to change the line endings of your script before the Linux version of `bash` can execute it properly.

Comment: I made a new shell script under windows `host_list="c15-0330-14.ad.mtu.edu\r" ssh "$host_list"`. But it returns `: Name or service not knownname c15-0330-14.ad.mtu.edu\\r`

Comment: It's not a literal backslash + r; it's the single ASCII character that represents  a carriage return. I just used `\r` to represent it.

Comment: Great, change line break from CRLF(`\r\n`) to LF(`\n`) worked for me!

Comment: This happened to me with Cygwin bash-- no matter what I tried, localhost, 127.0.0.1, my IP address, nothing worked. However, when I used Notepad++ to convert the CR LF endings to LF endings, it worked perfectly.